# Enum in typescript has limit of 25 elements

Tags: typescript, types, enums

I have a problem to adding more then 25 elements to enum. I have enum like this:

```js
enum Type {
    type1 ,
    type2 ,
    type3 ,
    type4 ,
    type5 ,
    type6 ,
    type7 ,
    type8 ,
    ...
    type25,
    type26
}
```

And also I have a map interface to set which enum value has a type:

```js
export interface MapperTypes {
    [Type.type1]: DifferentType1
    [Type.type2]: DifferentType2
    [Type.type3]: DifferentType3
    [Type.type4]: DifferentType1
    [Type.type5]: DifferentType2
    [Type.type6]: DifferentType3
    [Type.type7]: DifferentType1
    ...
    [Type.type25]: DifferentType1
    [Type.type26]: DifferentType1
}
```

And when I am adding the `Type.type26` then I had an error in this function:

```js
function createLog(params: TypeParams) {
     new Log({
        type: params.type, // Type 'Type' is not assignable to type 'Type.type26'.(2322)
        userId: params.userId,
    })
}
```

But if I am using less or equal to 25 elements in enum then everything is ok.

How I could add 26 and more elements to enum?

[Here the link with full example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-eTcyzQjHGdWQvaK8b9dQ3ZiwzaGxEfR2UzmS1GaCG+9n630bvcni8sqMAAofYofGCg7ao16IQgYrCmgxoZoIfzsKAtEoAST250OR9wH3q9VyeFyDwgHwANmeIPknjAPk+XwA-M0-yAiUIKQrCcAAD5wNAb5vv4fSpM6sIZNc4BTs8cBfG+HwtKCAAyDw9Due5gEBm5oGh7BfC+5xQF8eBPAAFCgxQPCgLQUfOi7Li0ACUYK7rgBRwKx7GcYJpHsDJDAABa5C0LLjGxHFKYwN44H07BIWh+RQBAjHPhA2GlH+YBEV0rG8SuB6EAuS4rlJR4QGAADucCWcx0myYwzQoDZ6mENYx6nsUF7+YFUInue9TWKk-FpEAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is on how you define `TypeParams`.

How about this:

```js
export type TypeParams<T extends Type = Type> = {
    type: T
    userId: string
    additionalInformation?: MapperTypes[T] | null
}
```

[Link for the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKApgdgrgtgBAFQJ4AcxwN6jjuAXVMARjgBptcC0AmMinKsAZjpF30IBZX3GBWHpUIA2QQ0IB2MRzQAOaYwCcCwkQAM5NkLREim3qur7txJsfE7O5mcT7XGRYfdUTnO2W%20KLP1DfRvUev6M1EbBhNRm4TRW0WDUdnHUwqAAvqCgjHAAIgCWAGb5YABOkHjIOnAAvJhwuQAmAFxwAM54xbkQAOZw6SBZeYUlZRXx1bUNzdAwAEYlvZmEOQVFpRDlhCw1GHVNre2dXQDcNs1tHd0LIKBgAB4oAPbFeHXrJfkAhgDG6ACyHyg0MVRi1MP4ANqjAB0DgAus1BqsRqoIdCQvDlkM1hsaKjCDDNhjEcN1qMmHi0AS0JwiSsSTjiBSwFSwHxaVjkbitDhIfjGMJ2UjSZsmSyJIL6aMiKLGLIJdjRtQZYRFPLOcxlTo1GrhTpNcQiDqGUruXBeZSHNQjWT9UQmNaUabzcyHDSEXSFRFbWz3RzdRqnWjVALfUKGdLA3yXA6uexnSyiHLQ5KRZGLapVcnPXq0y6Itqs%20qTXGgzRDYX-eTcyzQjHGdWQvaK8b9dQ3ZiwzaGxEfR2UzmS1GaCG%209n630bvcni8sqMAAofYofGAtAA8CDgdzwkHqoNG41GAD5xlhTYxmgh-FAWiUAJJ7c6Hfwfer1XJ4XIPCAfAA2t4g%20RPDAHwfl%20AD8zT-ICJQgpCsJwAAPnA0A-j%20aQZNc4BTs8cBfD%20HwtKCAAyDw9KeBhoBBiCEBh7BfF%205xQF8eBPAAFCgxQPCgLRUfOi7Li0ACUYKmuwBRwOxnHccJ5HsHJDAABa5C0LLjBxXEqYw-jsH0OnoZh%20RQBAzGfhAuGlCBYAkV07H8SuF6EAuS4rjJ2kQGAADucDWaxsnyeecAoHZmmENY7DXneexBc5KkRcU97WKkglpEAA)